# html put a link beside each table row

Tags: html, css

I have a table, each row contains of three columns, i want for each row to add a link beside it.

```
<table>
    <th>
        Name:
    </th>
    <th>
        Price:
    </th>
    <th>
        Description
    </th>

    <?php while ($row = $foods->fetch()) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['foodPrice']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?>
            </td>
        <a class="editLink">roma</a>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

I tried to add a link `a` after the last `td` but that links becomes at the top of the table,
thanks in advance

Comment: Why you just dont add another <td> to each <tr> to hold the link?

Comment: because this makes all the tds the same width

Comment: u can add class to the specific <td> to control the width right?

Comment: i don't know , but does this way make all the tds with the same width?

Comment: ok i will add a code snippet below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a table cell to contain the link.  Also the `th` tags should be surrounded with a `tr` tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name:
        </th>
        <th>
            Price:
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($row = $foods->fetch()) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['Name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['foodPrice']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['foodDescription']; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="link"><!-- Your missing this -->
                <a class="editLink">roma</a>
            </td><!-- and this -->
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

To style the link cell different from the others you will need to use CSS.  Add a CSS class of `link` to the `td` containing your `a` tag.  Then define the styling as follows:

**CSS**

```
table{
    text-align: center;
}

td{
    width: 200px;
}

td.link{
    width: 50px;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/y9C3G/

Comment: this is what i have already tried, the link because at the top of the table, not beside the row

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Your example in the post shows that you have not surrounded the link with `td` tags, my example is slightly different in that the link is surrounded by `td` tags.  Look for the comments in my markup

Comment: yes it know this way, but in your way all the fields have the same width, i want the link to be with small width, because it is just a link and it doesn't make any sence if its width is equal to a field such as Description field

Comment: i am trying it, sorry i am new to this things

Comment: @KevinBowersox how this is different from my answer ;)

Comment: @Razmig When things boil down its not very different, I guess the main difference is mine was post 16 minutes prior to yours

Comment: True, but edited 3 mins after my post. anyway all work is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid to have an `<a>` tag directly inside a `<tr>` like that. Add another column to the table by putting the link in its own cell. You also probably want to add another `<th>` in the first row, or add a `colspan="2"` attribute to the Description one.

Also, a table is required to contain a `<tbody>` element, and I suggest putting your `<th>`s in a `<thead>`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is colsan? and if i add a new td, that makes all the cells in the row with the same width, i don't want that, because it is just a link and i have a field contains a lot of words

Comment: A colspan instructs a cell how many columns it should span. For example, you can have a table with five columns, but one row with a single cell, if you set `rowspan="5"` on that cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td>Your Content</td>
    <td class="myLinkClass"><a href=""></a></td>
</tr>

<style>
    .myLinkClass {
        width: 100px; /* This will give width for only the td with this class */ 
    }
</style>
```